# How kubernetes know which type of container I use?

Tags: kubernetes

Sorry, I'm new to kubernetes.

I have read many kubernete conf for docker.

But it seems no conf specific the container is docker.

So how kubernetes know it should create docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kubernetes supports using alternate container runtimes (such as rkt), but it currently assumes that the images that are being launched are Docker images. Support for specifying alternate image types is being discussed in [kubernetes#7203](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7203).